# Ethercat interface to elmo motor controllers

Tags: ros, ros-control, ethercat, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'd like to drive an [Elmo DC Whistle motor controller](http://www.elmomc.com/products/DC-whistle-servo-drive-gold.htm) via Ethercat in ROS.

I've look around quite a bit and found several questions like #q256404, #q240550 or #q199494 which are basically all: use [SOEM](http://wiki.ros.org/soem); or #q226843 which relates to [ros_ethercat](https://github.com/shadow-robot/ros_ethercat).
Actually, #q256404 and #q240550 are exact duplicats, but only answered with the generic "use soem" approach. (I am able to run the `simple_test` client provided with soem, so the system is operational)

I don't want to depend on Orocos, afair, this is required when you want to use `rtt_soem` which is in some answers as well.

However, I'd like to use `ros_control`, if possible, so `ros_ethercat` seems like a great start.

In the end, I do have problems about how to approach writing the driver, though. Does anyone now of an example how to use `ros_ethercat` with `CustomHW` and CoE? Any help would be highly appreciated.

(System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 with ROS Kinetic)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283492/ethercat-interface-to-elmo-motor-controllers/) by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 12390 on 2018-02-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2018-10-23**:
@mgruhler have you come up with something shareable? I have got an Elmo DC Whistle too and I'll need to integrate it in ROS in the following months.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-11-21**:
@alextoind Yes, I've been able to implement something. However, I cannot share the full code.
I might be able to extract the relevant snippets though, if you are interested. However, I ended up using SOEM, not `ros_ethercat` (I was lost on that one)...

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2018-11-21**:
@mgruhler thanks for the feedback! I've not started to work on it yet, but I'll try with SOEM then and I'll let you know ;)

**Comment by [Hao Deng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30788/hao-deng/) on 2018-12-18**:
@mgruhler My hardware connection is like this: I have four Gold Solo Whistle and one Gold Maestro, connected in EOE. My current issue is the SOEM could find any slaves, I am asking do we need the standard configuration in Elmo Application Studio or any special configuration for ROS connection? Thank

**Comment by [Hao Deng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30788/hao-deng/) on 2018-12-18**:
@mgruhler I post my problem [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/311048/ethercat-interface-to-elmo-motor-controller/). And hope you can notice and help me.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-03-12**:
@alextoind I know this is now really late to the party, but I finally managed to upload [a gist](https://gist.github.com/mgruhler/7ccb12d95c4d171b64aa3d7ea82cc1a7) of an adapted `simpletest` file of SOEM to interface with two Elmo Gold DC Whistle.
You should be able to work from there (but most probably have resorted to some other solution or figured it out by now :-) )

Note that the most critical thing was to get the PDO mappings right...

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2019-03-12**:
You are great! I had few delays in the project so it is perfectly on time :D
And, as you said, the PDO mappings were the most scary things to test. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not a real example (as in: intended to be one), but the [sr-ronex-test](https://github.com/shadow-robot/sr-ronex) pkgs appear to be using `ros_ethercat` to interface with RoNeX hw. Perhaps those could be used to learn from.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-26**:
@gvdhoorn Great. I don't know why I did not stumble upon this one. This could help. It is actually the first package I've seen actually implementing a driver upon `ros_ethercat`.
If you post as an answer, I'll accept that.